# Sending and receiving over network using TcpClient (socket or Stream) fails after X interactions

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server, tcpclient

I have a couple very simple socket programs to do length-prefixed string sending and receiving.  Here's the core routines:

```
// Send a string, length-prefixed, to a socket.
public static void SendStringToSocket(Socket socket, string str)
{
    byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    Console.WriteLine("SendStringToSocket: " + dataBuffer.Length);
    byte[] lengthBuffer = LengthToNetworkBytes(dataBuffer.Length);
    byte[] overallBuffer = new byte[dataBuffer.Length + lengthBuffer.Length];

    for (int b = 0; b < lengthBuffer.Length; ++b)
        overallBuffer[b] = lengthBuffer[b];

    for (int d = 0; d < dataBuffer.Length; ++d)
        overallBuffer[d + lengthBuffer.Length] = dataBuffer[d];

    Console.WriteLine("SendStringToSocket: Sending " + overallBuffer.Length);
    socket.Send(overallBuffer);
    Console.WriteLine("SendStringToSocket: Complete");
}

// Read a length-prefixed string from a socket.
public static string ReadStringFromSocket(Socket socket)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    bool bReadLength = false;
    int nStrLen = -1;
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Length);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...");
        int nRead = socket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        if (nRead == 0)
            break;

        int nOffset = 0;
        if (!bReadLength)
        {
            byte[] lenBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            if (nRead < lenBuffer.Length)
                throw new RuntimeException(ErrorCode.NetworkError, "Reading string length failed.");

            for (int b = 0; b < lenBuffer.Length; ++b)
                lenBuffer[b] = buffer[b];

            nStrLen = NetworkBytesToLength(lenBuffer);
            Console.WriteLine("ReadStringFromSocket: Length: " + nStrLen);
            if (nStrLen < 0)
                throw new RuntimeException(ErrorCode.NetworkError, "Invalid string length: " + nStrLen + " - be sure to convert from host to network");

            bReadLength = true;
            nOffset = lenBuffer.Length;

            if (nStrLen == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with no length");
                if (nRead != lenBuffer.Length)
                    throw new RuntimeException(ErrorCode.NetworkError, "Zero length string has more data sent than expected.");
                return "";
            }
        }

        memStream.Write(buffer, nOffset, nRead - nOffset);

        if (memStream.Length > nStrLen)
            throw new RuntimeException(ErrorCode.NetworkError, "More string data sent than expected.");

        if (memStream.Length == nStrLen)
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with " + memStream.Length + " bytes");
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memStream.Length);
}
```

I think these routines embody the best practices for this sort of thing.

Here's the client app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StringSocketClient <server address> <server port>");
        return;
    }

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(args[0], int.Parse(args[1]));
    Socket socket = client.Client;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("> ");

        string strInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Sending...");
        Utils.SendStringToSocket(socket, strInput);

        Console.WriteLine("Receiving...");
        string strResponse = Utils.ReadStringFromSocket(socket);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:");
        Console.WriteLine(strResponse);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Here's the server app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StringSocketEchoServer <TCP port to serve>");
        return;
    }

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(args[0]));
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        new Thread(ProcessConnection).Start(client);
    }
}

static void ProcessConnection(object state)
{
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)state;
    Socket socket = client.Client;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading from network...");
            string str = Utils.ReadStringFromSocket(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + str);

            Console.WriteLine("Sending back...");
            Utils.SendStringToSocket(socket, str);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION!\r\n" + exp);
        try
        {
            client.Close();
            client = null;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Real straightforward, simple stuff, cut down to the bone of the problem.

What I'm finding is that if I do five interactions, the client hangs trying to receive a response, and the server is trying to receive a request.  Here's the console outputs:

Client:

> foobar
>       Sending...
>       SendStringToSocket: 6
>       SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
>       SendStringToSocket: Complete
>       Receiving...
>       ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
>       ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
>       ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
>       Response:
>       foobar

```
> foobar
Sending...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Receiving...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Response:
foobar

> foobar
Sending...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Receiving...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Response:
foobar

> foobar
Sending...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Receiving...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Response:
foobar

> foobar
Sending...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Receiving...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
^CPress any key to continue . . .
```

Server:

```
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Received: foobar
Sending back...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Received: foobar
Sending back...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Received: foobar
Sending back...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
ReadStringFromSocket: Length: 6
ReadStringFromSocket: Complete with 6 bytes
Received: foobar
Sending back...
SendStringToSocket: 6
SendStringToSocket: Sending 10
SendStringToSocket: Complete
Reading from network...
ReadStringFromSocket: Reading...
```

Earlier in the day, it was three interactions then the hang.

I think the code's correct.  It works X times.  But then it hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry about the messed up Client: / Server: output.  Let me know if you need clarification beyond what's dumped above.

Comment: It may not be clear from the Client: / Server: output, but at the end of the day, the client thinks the Send went fine and it proceeds to trying to Receive the server response, but the server just stays at receiving the request, as though the data the client sent is stuck or got dropped or something.

Comment: The client is in my office.  The server is on an AWS EC2.  I've tried disabling my local security software, disabling the Windows Firewall on the server, using a different AWS EC2.  That strange five times...

Comment: You have several objects which implement `IDisposable`, but which are not in `using` blocks. Your `MemoryStream`, `TcpClient` and `Socket` instances at the very least. One frequent symptom of not implementing `using` blocks is that operations fail "after a while".

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  I don't think test apps need using blocks...I don't see how adding the using blocks would change the problem I'm facing...it's not a resource leak, it's a networking problem.  Another clue: Wireshark says TCP Retransmission a bunch of times in the hanging case.

Comment: You don't think that the protocol could be affected by resources not being disposed of in the case of exceptions?

Comment: Thanks for having another look.  There aren't any exceptions being thrown.  These aren't meant to be production-grade network apps.  They're just cut down to the bone to stay simple and readable.  Is ther anything more I can explain about parameters of the situation?

Comment: If you want to "cut to the bone", then you want to eliminate anything that is not crucial to the problem. So get rid of the try/catch blocks, and put in the `using` blocks, and see if it still happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify that the client and server - with code stripped back to even simpler versions that posted above - interact perfectly fine for lots and lots of interactions when an East Coast client hits a West Coast server.  Must be something in my local networking.  Not a software problem.  Thanks to everybody for your insights.

Comment: Yep, turns out our intranet was not allowing outgoing traffic to go to the server's port.  Not sure why it worked X times at all, but once they twiddled their bits, all went well.  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Stream class to write and receive data, it might be more reliable then the Socket class. example:

```
TcpClient conn = new TcpClient();
Stream stream;                    // read and write data to stream
try
{
   string msg = "this is a test";
   conn.Connect("localhost", 50000);
   stream = conn.GetStream();
   byte[] by = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg.ToCharArray(), 0, msg.Length);
   await stream.WriteAsync(by, 0, by.Length);     // write bytes to buffer
   stream.Flush();                                // send bytes, clear buffer

   by = new byte[2048];  // new byte array to store received data

   //wait until buffer has data, then returns buffer length
   int bytesAvailable = await stream.ReadAsync(by, 0, 2048);
   msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(by, 0, bytesAvailable);
} catch (Exception e) { //output exception
}
```

This is what I did for a Win 8 ui app. Because of that, you could probably get away with the regular Read and Write methods of stream, which do not need await before calling. i.e.

```
stream.Write(by, 0, by.Length);
stream.Read(by, 0, 2048);
```

By the way, if you ever do this in Win 8 store app, you need a Stream object for reading and another for writing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Unfortunately, using code very similar to what I initially posted, replacing the socket code with stream code, I get the same behavior.  I can do the same interaction five times, then on the sixth it hangs.  The console indicates that the client completed sending and is now trying to receive, but the server is just sitting there trying to receive.  Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: FWIW - I tried using Begin / End async I/O, with streams and not sockets, so it's totally different code, and it still hangs after five successes.  Something at the TCP level...  I'm really tearing my hair out on this one!

Comment: FWIW - I posted a cut-down description of the symptoms to Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/574216/tcp-client-and-server-work-for-x-times-but-hang-after-that

Comment: Some where along the way either the client or server is not successfully sending the message. Have you debugged to check for that? Also, maybe this was a typo, but does your server actually repeat the first two lines of the output before actually continuing? Also, I suggest adding an identifier to your messages, hard code a message to the front or back of the message. Create an application protocol so that the client knows it is communicating with the correct server and vice-versa.

Comment: No exceptions are raised.  The client think's it's sent the request, but the server gives no indication of the request arriving.  I was able to send different messages in (1, 2, 3, etc.) and the server got the right stuff and echoed it back correctly.  We're down to it hanging on the third request now.

Comment: As posted on Server Fault, I realized that I could test the client running on something other than my computer, and when I run it on an AWS EC2 in the same region everything works.  I'll try spinning up an EC2 in another region and see what smokes there.

Comment: stream.Flush is according to MSDN documentation "reserved for future use" and has no effect.